# How to determine coordinates of fragment relative to its mesh

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm trying to do a tile system using ThreeJS shaders.
I thought I would start with a PlaneBufferGeometry with a gradient fill (ShaderMaterial).

I'm really new to GLSL and I am struggling to find a way to determine coordinates of a fragment inside its mesh (to calculate the gradient value).

To be clear, I am looking for the same variable `position` used in these examples:
http://pixelshaders.com/sample/

Code (Fragment shader):

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 position;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor.r = position.x;
  gl_FragColor.g = 0.0;
  gl_FragColor.b = 0.0;
  gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

But the example only show the code for the fragment shader, so I don't get how he construct that variable.

I tried to declare the same variable in my vertex shader :

```
varying vec2 position;
```

but I got the following error (Chrome console) :

> THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() ERROR: 0:77: 'position' : redefinition

It seems like Three.js alredy setup something called 'position' in the vertex shader :

```
attribute vec3 position;
```

But I'm pretty sure I need to make my own vec2 variable, I just don't get how to calculate it.

Any hint will be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `position` is reserved by THREE.js to pass the vertex attribute `position` to the vertex shader. Just name the variable different than `position`. You can use this instead --

Vertex Shader:

```
varying vec2 vPosition;

void main() {
  // your calculation
  vPosition = position.xy;
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying vec2 vPosition;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor.r = vPosition.x;
  gl_FragColor.g = 0.0;
  gl_FragColor.b = 0.0;
  gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

Also, you can use the built-in variable `gl_FragCoord` to achieve what you are looking for. In that way, you dont have to use an extra variable.

Fragment shader:

```
void main() {
      gl_FragColor.r = gl_FragCoord.x/WINDOW_WIDTH;
      gl_FragColor.g = 0.0;
      gl_FragColor.b = 0.0;
      gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
    }
```